# Passing a container of unique_ptr to constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, containers, move, unique-ptr

What am I missing here?  Why can't I move a vector as part of class constructor?  Removing const from the constructor doesn't help either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Bar
{
public:
  Bar(const vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec);
  vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec_;
};

Bar::Bar(const vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec) :
  vec_(move(vec)) //not ok
{
}

int main()
{
  vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec;
  vec.push_back(unique_ptr<char>(new char('a')));
  vec.push_back(unique_ptr<char>(new char('b')));
  vec.push_back(unique_ptr<char>(new char('c')));
  vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec1 (move(vec)); //ok
  Bar bar(vec1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what problem you are having; if the code fails to compile then post the compiler error messages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following [should compile fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd2e74d018026620):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Bar
{
public:
  Bar(vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec);
  vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec_;
};

Bar::Bar(vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec) : // If you intend to move something,
                                         // do not make it const, as moving
                                         // from it will in most cases change
                                         // its state (and therefore cannot be
                                         // const-qualified).
  vec_(move(vec))
{
}

int main()
{
  vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec;
  vec.push_back(unique_ptr<char>(new char('a')));
  vec.push_back(unique_ptr<char>(new char('b')));
  vec.push_back(unique_ptr<char>(new char('c')));
  vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec1 (move(vec));
  Bar bar(std::move(vec1)); // Just like the line immediately above,
                            // the explicit `move` is required, otherwise
                            // you are requesting a copy, which is an error.
  return 0;
}
```

I have left the rest of your code unchanged, but you may want to read [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4):

This code works fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Bar
{
    Bar(vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec)
        : Vec(move(vec))
    { }

    vector<unique_ptr<char>> Vec;
};

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec;
    vec.push_back(unique_ptr<char>(new char('a')));
    vec.push_back(unique_ptr<char>(new char('b')));
    vec.push_back(unique_ptr<char>(new char('c')));

    vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec1(move(vec));

    Bar bar(move(vec1));
}
```

Note that I removed the `const` in the constructor parameter, and I also added an explicit `move` when constructing `bar` in `main()`.

In fact, you had this code in `main()`:

> ```
> vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec1 (move(vec)); //ok
> Bar bar(vec1);
> ```

But that code required a *copy* of the `vec1` vector when constructing `bar`. Since `vec1` is defined as a `vector` of `unique_ptr`s, and since `unique_ptr` is movable but *not copyable*, the compiler issued an error: it is not possible to copy the `vec1` vector.

Instead, you must be explicit in calling `std::move()` on the `vec1` argument if you want to trigger a *move* of the vector argument.

Answer (score 2):

This constructor (with or without const) accepts a vector **by value**:

```
Bar::Bar(const vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec)
```

Pass-by-value means that a vector `vec` is constructed by copying the argument passed.  However, a `unique_ptr` is not copyable. Therefore, this function can only be called with an xvalue (that is, a temporary vector that is about to be destroyed anyway, or a vector which you have explicitly permitted to be moved out of by calling `std::move` or otherwise).

So to call this constructor:

```
Bar bar( vec1 );               // FAIL: not allowed to take a copy of vec1
Bar bar( std::move(vec1) );    // OK: move pointers out of vec1 in order to create bar
```

You *could* avoid this problem by having `Bar::Bar` take the vector by non-const reference. However this would lead to unintuitive behaviour if that constructor moved elements out of its argument, so the way you have it is perhaps best.

---

The second part of the problem is what `Bar::Bar` does once you have actually managed to call it. In this version:

```
Bar::Bar(const vector<unique_ptr<char>> vec) : vec_(move(vec))
```

it fails because you cannot move out of a `const` vector. To fix this, take out the word `const` which was serving no purpose anyway.  (The first part of the problem is unaffected by whether the parameter is `const` or not).